# How to compile OpenCV with extra modules on OS X?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv, opencv3.0

I've previously compiled OpenCV 3.0 successfully following [this guide](http://blogs.wcode.org/2014/10/howto-install-build-and-use-opencv-macosx-10-10/), which essentially consists of the following steps:

- Download all the prerequisites (XCode, Command Line Tools, CMake and OpenCV source)
- Build static libs by configuring CMake (via gui) with:

  - Uncheck BUILD_SHARED_LIBS
  - Uncheck BUILD_TESTS
  - Add an SDK path to CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT (if it matters, I used `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk`).
  - **Add x86_64 to CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES** (emphasis mine, this seems to be the issue, I'm sure I've followed this step)
  - Uncheck WITH_1394
  - Uncheck WITH_FFMPEG
- Configure and generate via CMake, then `make` and `sudo make install` from the CLI.

All of the above alone works fine.

---

I'm now looking to compile OpenCV with [the extra modules](https://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib). According to their read-me it should be as simple as filling out `OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH` to `<opencv_contrib>/modules` in CMake and then building as usual.

I followed the steps outlined above with the added parameter and building OpenCV succeeds, however, when trying to use one of the extra modules in a program (namely `cv::ximgproc::createStructuredEdgeDetection`, if it matters), I'm getting the following error when compiling:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   `"cv::ximgproc::createStructuredEdgeDetection(cv::String const&, cv::Ptr<cv::ximgproc::RFFeatureGetter const>)"`, referenced from:
>   _main in main.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've included the header which should include the above:

```
#include <opencv2/ximgproc.hpp>
```

I'm compiling via XCode, where I've set an additional header search path of `/usr/local/include` and a library search path of `/usr/local/lib` for the project, am I missing something here?

Standard OpenCV functionality works fine.

What could be the issue and how would I go about solving it?

Comment: have you added the contrib libs to your dependency? The rest seems correct

Comment: @Miki Thanks a lot for your comment, I missed that. I originally had other linker flags `-lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_videostab`, but I didn't include `-lopencv_ximgproc`. The compilation succeeds with the latter added. Is there an easy way to find out all of the includes that are provided?

Comment: You should find all libs under your `<OPENCV_DIR>/install/` folder. `<OPENCV_DIR>/install/x86/vc12/staticlib` in my build

Comment: @Miki You've been a tremendous help, I've been trying to solve this for quite a while now, thank you. If you want to write a short answer, I'd happily accept it.

Comment: This post was very helpful, please upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV contrib modules are built correctly.

You just need to add the contrib libs to your dependencies, in this case adding: `-lopencv_ximgproc`.

---

All available libs can be found under `<OPENCV_DIR>/install/` folder. 
E.g. in my 32bit vc12 static build are in`<OPENCV_DIR>/install/x86/vc12/staticlib` folder.