# How to build OpenCV with extra modules from opencv_contrib on Xcode?

Tags: macos, opencv, opencv3.0

Not sure how to go about this have been searching and can't really find the solution I need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compile OpenCV with extra modules on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33157592/how-to-compile-opencv-with-extra-modules-on-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

Solved through it based on the official guide from opencvs github page https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.